# R - stackplot/barplot proportion over time

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to realise a distribution plot like this one

[image]

For each period, I need to graph the "stacked proportion".

The data look like this basically :

```
         400 401 402 403 404 ...
1013662   7   7   7   7   7
1024583   2   2   2   2   2
1024812   6  27  27  27  27
1025491  48  48  48  48  48
1036642  56  56  56  56  56
....
```

I thought of something like

```
ft = function(x) prop.table(table(x), NULL)
apply(dta, MARGIN = 2, FUN = ft)
```

I would then have a list of proportion for each time period

```
$`400`
2    6    7   19   24   30   42   46   48   56   67 
0.05 0.05 0.45 0.05 0.10 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
```

I am not sure what the next step would be. 
I do not know how to properly `unlist` and store in a dataframe ?

Any idea ?

(I tried the basic `barplot(as.matrix(dta))` but it did not seem right).

Here is my data

```
 dta = structure(c(7L, 2L, 6L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 46L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 
        7L, 19L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 67L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 
        7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 
        27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 
        56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 
        42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 
        7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 
        7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 27L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 67L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 
        49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 
        56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 
        42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 
        7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 
        7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 
        49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 
        56L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 67L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 
        42L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 
        7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 
        7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 
        49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 
        7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 
        42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 
        7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 
        7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 20L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 
        49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 
        7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 
        42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 
        7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 
        7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 
        49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 49L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 7L, 
        7L, 22L, 7L, 21L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 
        42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 
        7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 
        7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 
        7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 
        4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 
        7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 
        7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 
        67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 
        42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 
        7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 48L, 67L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 22L, 7L, 18L, 7L, 30L, 7L, 24L, 42L, 68L
), .Dim = c(20L, 51L), .Dimnames = list(c("1013662", "1024583", 
                                      "1024812", "1025491", "1036642", "1037551", "1037552", "1037991", 
                                      "1037992", "1040291", "1040292", "1041101", "1041212", "1041651", 
                                      "104221", "104222", "104331", "104332", "104992", "1052571"), 
                                    c("400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", 
                                      "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
                                      "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", "425", 
                                      "426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", "434", 
                                      "435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", "443", 
                                      "444", "445", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450")))
```

Comment: `barplot(prop.table(dta,margin=2))` perhaps?

Comment: very nice ... any idea how I could control the colours ? like attributing one value to one colour ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `ggplot2`, `dplyr` and `reshape2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
dta2 <- dta %>% melt %>%
                group_by(Var2, value) %>%
                summarise(count = n( )/nrow(dta))
ggplot(dta2, aes(x = Var2, fill = factor(value), y = count)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, colour = "black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

After reading rather than skimming the post, I understand that you are wanting to plot the proportions of frequencies of the values. The numerical values themselves do not matter (they could be thought of or coerced to factors if desired).

Then one way to do this is to stack and count with `table`.

```
 barplot(table(stack(as.data.frame(dta)))/nrow(dta),space=0,col=rainbow(nrow(dta)))
```

[image: proportioned bar plot in color]

Comment: i am the impression that there is an error. I am not sure but I think that because the value are different for each period, the colours then do not match. Because each colours should represent a value, but if this value is not in the time period, then the same colour (because of the order) will be attributed to another value. You see ?

Comment: I understand now, see edits. I also didn't realize your example picture was based on the example data. We appear to match.